# Images missing after I imported a Joomla website to wordpress using FG joomla pluggin

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, joomla

I migrated a Joomla website to WordPress using FG joomla plugin. All Joomla articles and categories were successfully imported but none of the intro or main article images were imported.

I uploaded the images into the media folder of the WordPress theme but still images were unable to display. I also installed some plugins to make the images display but it did not work unfortunately.

My question is how can I make the full article images in the Joomla articles show as main post images in WordPress?

Comment: Could you explain more on the steps you used to reproduce this error? Which steps did you apply and which were the errors shown (if there are).

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't already tried, you might want to force media imports by checking the appropriate box in the plugin configuration > behavior.

Update: According to [this FAQ](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi0jO3A6eTRAhXn1IMKHTlMDosQFggpMAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwordpress.org%2Fplugins-wp%2Ffg-joomla-to-wordpress%2F&usg=AFQjCNExJBHHRVQgkZ47xjjPblaG17hrEA) if media isn't imported you want to:

> Check the URL field that you filled in the plugin settings. It must be
>   your Joomla home page URL and must start with http://

Another possible reason could be missing php extensions on your server. According to https://wordpress.org/plugins/fg-joomla-to-wordpress/faq/

> The media are not imported and I get the error message: "Warning:
>   copy() [function.copy]: URL file-access is disabled in the server
>   configuration"
>
> in php.ini to copy the medias. If your remote host doesn't allow this
>   directive, you will have to do the migration on localhost. The PHP directive "Allow URL fopen" must be turned on

If you still don't have any success, you could check error logs for both your Joomla and WordPress site, maybe you'll be lucky and see some clues there.

If still no joy, maybe you'll need to contact the plugin developer.

Good luck!

[image]

Comment: I checked the box but no intro images or full article images were imported

Comment: When you view the WordPress site, are there broken links where you would expect to see the images? @apprentice01

Comment: No there are no broken link or any sign that there could be any image there.

Comment: hey @apprentice01, please see my update above

Comment: thanks very much for your help. I have tried all that but it still didn't work